# Два блока с заданной одинаковой высотой выводятся разными по высоте

Tags: html, css, height

Сделан блок "кнопок" сбоку страницы, с выплывающим нижним блоком. В зависимости от {margin-bottom} блока [.block-for-one] у разных кнопок вылазит снизу нижняя граница.

Как сделать полностью одинаковыми по высоте верхний и нижний блок? Хотя они одной высоты.

Возможно что-то зависит от того как браузер рендит страницы, на мобильных устройствах, например, нет такого нежелательного эффекта.
Возможно это только в Firefox. Наверно какое-то свойство не поддерживается

Ну ладно бы все блоки смещались, а то ведь только некоторые, и всё время разные в зависимости от того, что убираешь. На сместившиеся блоки помогает {top:-1px;}, но он и нормальные сдвигает.

Если сделать высоту главного первого родительского блока {height: 50px;} нижняя граница появится у красного блока, вместо черного.

Сайт http://jurvrn.ru

Код не выкладываю, хотелось бы разобраться на живом сайте.
[image: скриншот 1]

[image: скриншот 2]

Comment: Если у вас включено масштабирование в браузере или операционной системе - то это погрешность рендеринга. При масштабировании 100% - такой проблемы не будет. Погрешность рендеринга при масштабировании не исправить. Эта проблема будет во всех браузерах, при разном масштабировании по разному. Сделайте всю плашку выезжающей.

Comment: а как? мне хотелось бы чтобы торчал "ярлычок", который бы оставался на месте.

Comment: попробуйте высоту в пикселях прописать родителю, а детям высоту 100%. но это может не сработать.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, обрезался предыдущий комментарий: .... мне хотелось бы чтобы торчал "ярлычок", который бы оставался на месте. Надо тогда не трансформацию использовать когда блок убирается за пределы экрана, а сделать ему нулевую ширину и разворачивать.... Как во втором варианте - сделал кнопки из списка - там нет таких искажений. Но хотелось бы оставить первый вариант. Просьба посмотреть и подсказать как исправить первый код.

Comment: upd. если убираю у одного из блоков стиль line-height: 35px; - то видно как замедленно поджимается высота вровень, как будто какие-то расчеты выполняются. Это можно увидеть на сайте - у сиреневой кнопки